# Does a Mass intention have any value now, if the Mass will be held, possibly, a year later?

Tags: catholicism, prayer, mass, covid-19

Does a *Mass intention* have any value now (as expressed, submitted and donation made now), if the Mass will be held, possibly, a year later (due to long waiting list of intentions)?

I would like to submit the intention/prayers for the possible success of the development of the Covid-19 vaccine. [Coronavirus treatment: Vaccines/drugs in the pipeline for COVID-19](https://www.clinicaltrialsarena.com/analysis/coronavirus-mers-cov-drugs/) is one list of ongoing projects, but there are other lists too), but I am afraid that the respective mass will be held after some half or full year from now, but our prayers for the all aspects of the development (scientific, political, business, economical, societal support) of vaccine are required exactly now!

Comment: I once asked this question to a theologian some years ago. He stated that as God knows all, it is not impossible that He could take things into consideration and apply it earlier than the actual Mass being said. Unfortunately, with no Catholic doctrine to affirm it, we must trust in God’s mercy. In any case, the Mass will always be meritorious, even if late!

Comment: Canon Law prohibits holding onto Mass intention stipends for more than a year anyways, but hopefully any COVID shutdown isn't stopping priests from privately saying Masses and thus working through any "backlog of intentions"

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, unequivocally, **'Yes'**.

After we all receive our COVID-19 vaccines and we attend Mass in person again, there will be a huge backlog of intentions for those who suffered illness and death during the quarantine. Churches and God the Father will respect all of these intentions both presently and retroactively. The Bible teaches us that every human life is sacred, and this teaching will most certainly be upheld after we are all vaccinated.

I know that this time is difficult, but please hold on. God is looking down on all of us now, and He will be there for us after the quarantine is over.